# Shade an area under density curve, to mark the Highest Density Interval (HDI)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I thought this should be straightforward, but I'm lost, despite tons of information online.

**My Problem:** I have a vector of data points, for which I want to plot a density curve, then color the area under the curve to signify the Highest Density Interval (HDI). Naturally, I'm trying to achieve this with `ggplot2` package, and specifically with `qplot()`, since my data comes as a vector, and not a data frame.

### Reproducible Example

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(HDInterval)

## create data vector
set.seed(789)
dat <- rnorm(1000)

## plot density curve with qplot and mark 95% hdi
qplot(dat, geom = "density")+ 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(hdi(dat))))
```

So I get this:

[image: density_curve]

But what I really want is something like this:

[image: what_i_want]

Is there a simple way to achieve this with `ggplot2::qplot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the ggridges package. The trick is that we can provide `HDInterval::hdi` as quantile function to `geom_density_ridges_gradient()`, and that we can fill by the "quantiles" it generates. The "quantiles" are the numbers in the lower tail, in the middle, and in the upper tail.

As a general point of advice, I would recommend against using `qplot()`. It's more likely going to cause confusion, and putting a vector into a tibble is not a lot of effort.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(HDInterval)
library(ggridges)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggridges'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     scale_discrete_manual

## create data vector
set.seed(789)
dat <- rnorm(1000)

df <- tibble(dat)

## plot density curve with qplot and mark 95% hdi
ggplot(df, aes(x = dat, y = 0, fill = stat(quantile))) + 
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(quantile_lines = TRUE, quantile_fun = hdi, vline_linetype = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("transparent", "lightblue", "transparent"), guide = "none")
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.227
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The colors in `scale_fill_manual()` are in the order of the three groups, so if you, for example, only wanted to shade the left tail, you would write `values = c("lightblue", "transparent", "transparent")`.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this post I was realy grateful for your answer, Wilke. But I wondered how to adjust the credible mass of the hdi. Finally I found a solution! When I figuered out where the quantiles argument comes from (I access it via dots[[2]]) it clicked the trigger. I wrote the following function (because passing the value to HDInterval::hdi didn't work out of the box):

```
hdi_custWidth <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  quantiles <- dots[[2]]
  hdi_width <- quantiles[[length(quantiles)]] # uses the last entry if its a vector which should be the biggest one; better pass a single double < 1.0
  if (is.na(hdi_width)) hdi_width <- .89 # happens is quantiles = 1L
  message(paste0('HDI credible interval width = ', hdi_width))
  HDInterval::hdi(dots[[1]], credMass = hdi_width)
}
```

You can use it to alter the repex from the post above:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(HDInterval)
library(ggridges)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggridges'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     scale_discrete_manual

## create data vector
set.seed(789)
dat <- rnorm(1000)

df <- tibble(dat)

## plot density curve with qplot and mark 95% hdi
ggplot(df, aes(x = dat, y = 0, fill = stat(quantile))) + 
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(quantile_lines = TRUE, quantile_fun = hdi_custWidth, quantiles = .90, vline_linetype = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("transparent", "lightblue", "transparent"), guide = "none")
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.227
```

Of course you can pick any value between 0 and 1 in the quantiles argument (not just .90) and get the corresponding hdi credible mass.